# ng-data-show not working properly with ui-select

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

If I use data-ng-show inside ui-select the input box takes width of 10px which is the inline style for that input box but if I remove the data-ng-show it works fine.
Why is it so? Is there any other solution for this?

```html
<ui-select multiple ng-model="data" data-ng-show="condition == 'xyz'" style="margin-top: 5px;" on-select="doSum()" on-remove="doSome()">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select timeperiod">
        {{$item.name}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="tp in data >
        {{tp.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

[image: As shown in this image the placeholder was hidden because of the inbuilt width of 10px]

As shown in this image the placeholder was hidden because of the inbuilt width of 10px

Comment: The inline style is `margin-top: 5px`, nothing about input width...

Comment: yes it deals with the margin only. In the dom it creates a <span> inside which a <input> is there which gets the width.

Comment: You should provide a Fiddle/Plunker of your code. It is difficult to understand what is your issue here.